# How to fix rectangle drawable misplaced on some phones

Tags: android

I have a rectangle drawable that is showing perfectly on my huawei y9 android 9 but it is not showing correctly on my lenovo api 19

Here are two pictures of the same drawable:
[image: Huawei y9]

[image: Lenovo 19 api]

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:top="0dp" android:bottom="10dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#40adc2" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="75%"
            android:pivotY="47%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
                <size
                    android:height="20dp"
                    android:width="15dp"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

As you can see the bottom blue rectangle is not where it should be on the lenovo phone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your activity code

Comment: There is nothing really in my activity code, just a text view with its background set to this drawable